# Parsing nested blocks in SQL using C#

Tags: c#, sql, parsing

i want to perform analysis on SQL code.
In this i would like to separate the blocks in SQL code.
for example, in the code below

```
for condition1 loop
stmt1;
for condition2 loop
stmt2;
end loop;
end loop;
```

i want to separate these two blocks and create a data structure which will contain outer loop block and will also have inner loop block.

which is the best way to do so? is there any parser available which can handle the nested loops in the best possible way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest composit pattern for this kind of blocks (and also for SELECT, CASE, WITH and similar).

```
public interface ICodeEntity { }
public interface IObjectEntity { }
public class Column: IObjectEntity
{
    public string name;
    public System.Data.DbType type;
}
public class Table: IObjectEntity
{
    public List<Column> columns = new List<Column>();
    public string alias;
}
public class Where : ICodeEntity { }
public class GroupBy : ICodeEntity { }
public class OrderBy : ICodeEntity { }
public class Select : Table, ICodeEntity
{
    public List<Table> joinList = new List<Table>();
    public Where where;
    public GroupBy groupBy;
    public OrderBy orderBy;
}
public class Condition : ICodeEntity { }
public class If : ICodeEntity
{
    public Condition condition;
    public List<ICodeEntity> codeList = new List<ICodeEntity>();
}
```

and somewhere in the program:

```
If if1 = new If();
if1.codeList.Add(new If());
```

see related links:
[CodeProject: Illustrated GOF Design Patterns in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/csdespat_2.aspx#Composite)
[data&object factory: Composite pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx)

Comment: hey thanks for your suggestion.
But these structures i would be creating after parsing is done.

My main concern is how shall i parse such loops? I mean is there any parser existing which can tokenize the strings in the code and can also tell me which type of statement is it like if/for loop?

Answer (score 0):

There should be already SQL Parser available that can do this automatically for you, you needn't reinvent the wheel. Just google "sql parser".